# GNU Emacs 24.1: forcing the TAB key to insert a <tab> character in ESS mode

Tags: emacs, ess

I almost never use the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key for anything except inserting a `<tab>` (`\t`) character. It is unacceptable to continue typing <kbd>C-q TAB</kbd> to do this, because I mostly use tabs for comments. Most of my code indentation is accomplished by Emacs automatically matching my first line of manual indentation, and by binding `indent-region` to <kbd>C-TAB</kbd>. I mostly use the tab key to indent my comments. I prefer to set my tab width to 8 characters and indent each of my comments by two tab characters for a total of 16 characters of white space. I would be OK living with the existing system for managing indentation if ESS were not prone to failure as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12903270/emacs-ess-mode-tab-stops-indenting). The file that I am currently working on has broken lines which cause exactly the problem described. At present, in that file, pressing the `tab` key produces NO result.

How does one force the tab key to insert a tab character in ESS[S] and ESS[SAS] modes?

I have tried adding

```
(global-set-key "\C-i" 'self-insert-command)
```

and

```
(setq-default tab-always-indent nil)
```

to my `.emacs` file, but this has not changed behavior in ESS. I cannot figure out what Emacs calls ESS[S] mode internally, i.e.,

```
(define-key ess-mode-map "\C-i" 'self-insert-command)
```

produces the error

> "Variable ess-mode-map is void."

I tried `ess-S-mode`, `ess-s-mode`, `ESS-S-mode`, and a few others with the same result.

I have also confirmed that `ess-mode-hook` and `ess-mode-map` are the expected hook and map variables. I then tried

```
(add-hook 'ess-mode-hook (lambda () (define-key "\t" ess-mode-map 'self-insert-command)))
```

which did not work.

I tried editing the ess-mode.el file and changing the keymap for "\t" to `'self-insert-command` which produced no effect.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Forcing emacs to use the tab character instead of a number of spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18970809/forcing-emacs-to-use-the-tab-character-instead-of-a-number-of-spaces)

Comment: Should be closed as a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/q/18970809/729907.

Comment: I contest, the issue is not that Emacs inserts spaces instead of a tab, it is that EMACS NEVER inserts a <tab> (\t) character upon TAB press in ESS mode. I want to change that default.

Comment: Oh, OK. In that case just bind `"\t"` to `self-insert-command` in the mode map.

Comment: I have been trying to do just that, but I can't figure out what ess-mode is called. `(global-set-key "\t" 'self-insert-command)` does not work and `(define-key ess-mode-map "\t" 'self-insert-command)` fails with error: "Symbol's value as variable is void: ess-mode-map"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The practical solution was simple, just add:

```
(add-hook 'ess-mode-hook (lambda () (local-set-key "\t" 'self-insert-command)))
```

to the `.emacs` file.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the map variable is not defined before the code defining the mode is loaded, or perhaps not even before the mode is enabled.

- If the first, then `require` the library before trying to bind the key. Or use `eval-after-load`.
- If the second, then put the binding on the mode hook:

  ```
  (add-hook 'THE-MODE-HOOK (lambda () (define-key "\t" THE-MODE-MAP 'self-insert-command)))
  ```

You might have to peek into the source code to find out what `THE-MODE-HOOK` and `THE-MODE-MAP` are.  Or you might get what you need from `C-h f THE-MODE`, where `THE-MODE` is the mode name.

Comment: I don't know what the library is called. it's not "ess-library". "ess" does not seem to refer to the mode either.

Comment: I'd say either wait to hear from someone who uses ESS here or take a look in the ESS manual... Or if you have the source code, presumably you can look for it (e.g., grep for `define-key`, `global-set-key`, `map` and so on). If not, hope someone has the complete answer for you.

Comment: I'm slowly working my way through the ess-mode manual and some of its .el files, thank you for the good suggestions.

Comment: It seems like the map variable is `ess-mode-map`, [defined in ess-mode.el](https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/blob/034383afad9ef08fde1b190e10881c21780ba0c2/lisp/ess-mode.el#L111).

Answer (score 1):

`M-i` is bound to `tab-to-tab-stop` in Emacs, which continuously adds 8 spaces but i'm sure that's customizable.  There are few more commands that might help you at [Indentation Commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Indentation-Commands.html#Indentation-Commands).

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your problem but these are the two alternative options:

1. Rebind the key locally:

   ```
   (define-key ess-mode-map "\C-i" 'self-insert-command)
   ```
2. Change the behavior of ess tab, which will make the <kbd>TAB</kbd> to indent only at the begining of the line, otherwise it will always insert plain `tab`:

   ```
   (setq ess-tab-always-indent nil)
   ```

Comment: You will notice in my question that I tried your first suggestion, and it did resulted in an error because "ess" does not refer to to ESS mode.

Comment: Then find out what the current keymap is, and bind it in that.

Comment: @user2127595, first load ESS then bind the key, or use ess-mode-hook as Drew suggested.

Comment: Hmm, `M-x local-set-key C-m TAB self-insert-command` worked. But the mode hook as listed in my question did not. How do I tell emacs to bind this key upon loading ESS?

Comment: wow, I'm a fool...`(add-hook 'ess-mode-hook (lambda () (local-set-key "\t" 'self-insert-command)))` worked perfectly. Thanks!